# Socket Programming between Client and Server to convert lowercase word/sentence to upper case word/sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-requests

I'm just starting out with python and I am trying to run a code wherein the client sends a message to the server in lower case AND the server returns the output in Upper case. The code is running correctly but, the get the output as:

```
Message from Server b"MESSAGE FROM CLIENT:B'POLL OIUOIU IUO'"
```

I'm getting that "B" after the : ,  Like I have shown  ⬆️

The code for **Client**:

```
import socket

 

msgFromClient       = input('Enter a word/sentence in lower case: ')

bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromClient)

serverAddressPort   = ("127.0.0.1", 20001)

bufferSize          = 1024

 

# Create a UDP socket at client side

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

 

# Send to server using created UDP socket

UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)

 

msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

 

msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])

print(msg)
```

Code for **Server**:

```
import socket

 

localIP     = "127.0.0.1"

localPort   = 20001

bufferSize  = 1024

 

msgFromServer       = "Hello UDP Client"

#bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromServer)

 

# Create a datagram socket

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

 

# Bind to address and ip

UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))

 

print("UDP server up and listening")

 

# Listen for incoming datagrams

while(1):

    #message,bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message,address = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    #message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    #address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = f'Message from Client:{message}'
    clientIP  = f"Client IP Address:{address}"
    
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)
    bytesToSend         = str.encode(clientMsg.upper())

   

    # Sending a reply to client

    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

How do I get a reply from server only like:

Message from Server: POLL OIUOIU IUO

(any sentence/word converted from lower case to upper case)

Please do help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors. One on each end. This is caused by the usage of the *`repr()` on the bytes*, used when formatting it as a string. This is also what adds the surrounding `'...'`. There are two errors, one indicated by the `b`, and the other by `B` (uppercase of b..).

Convert the bytes to a *string* first, as so, to fix the `b` error:

```
bytesFromServer, _ = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
msgFromServer = bytesFromServer.decode()
```

The `B` error originates from:

```
message,address = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
```

Rename message to messageBytes or similar and properly decode it as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I modified the code like you said. But I get the error: 
   messagefromserver=bytesFromServer.decode()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: `bytesFromServer, address = ..` or discard the 2nd value - answer updated as well.

Comment: messageBytes,address = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    mfs=messageBytes.decode()

    #message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    #address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = f'{mfs}'
    clientIP  = f"Client IP Address:{address}"
    
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)
    bytesToSend         = str.encode(clientMsg.upper())
    #print(bytesToSend)

   

    # Sending a reply to client

    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)

This code updated. But still output 
Message from Server b'JKJKJ'

Comment: So it’s fixed the `B` issue? Good. Then apply the same fix on the server. The `b'...'` indicates that there is an byte array incorrectly being converted to a string. Go back through the server code and ensure it correctly decoded the value into a string, and that string is used for display.